# How to add comments to AuditInfo from UI input?

Tags: abp

I see [in the documents there is a PostContributer](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/7.4//Audit-Logging#audit-log-contributors) we could use to add comments to the AuditLog. In the example it was a default string added.
How can I add the comment passed on by UI input (Angular) ?

```
public class MyAuditLogContributor : AuditLogContributor {

public override void PostContribute(AuditLogContributionContext context)
{
    context.AuditInfo.Comments.Add("Some comment...");
}}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the comment from the UI to the application service in the DTO. Then inject the `IAuditingManager` in your application service create or update method you can use it like:

```cs
var currentAuditLogScope = _auditingManager.Current;
if (currentAuditLogScope != null)
{
    currentAuditLogScope.Log.Comments.Add(input.Comment);
}
```